# Backbone marionette coffeescript bind scope

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette, backbone-views

This is a simple backbone view class that i have:

```
class Student.Views.SharedChat extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
  template: 'student/shared/chat/chat'

  onRender: ->
    Student.CurrentUserChannel.bind('student:chat_threads:created', @setUpThread)

  setUpThread: (data) ->
    channel = Student.Pusher.subscribe("presence-thread-1")
    channel.bind('student:chat_messages:created', @newMessage) 

  newMessage: (data) ->
   do something with data...

end
```

My question is, how do i call @newMessage, from what the above code looks like, the channel binding to the @newMessage does not recognize it within that scope, how do i access newMessage function from that binding?

Appreciate your replies, this is kind of driving me against the wall.

---

Though i had tried the fat arrows before, but i guess i did not not totally understand it. niko's reply made me think and read about it a bit more. The problem was that the @setUpThread itself was being called as a function that was already binded, so the fat arrow needed to be for @setUpThread to maintain @ and not for @newMessage.

Comment: Have you tried the fat-arrow? `newMessage: (data) =>`

Comment: yes i have, and it still does not recognize it.

Comment: Ah, i finally got it! i am going to edit the question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
channel.bind('student:chat_messages:created', (data)=>@newMessage(data))
```